# Dynamically fit webpage into browser vertically

Tags: javascript, css, resize, liquid, fluid-layout

I'm relatively new to all of this and have been working on a page for the last week. I've found this site to be very useful so far but I can't seem to get my page to dynamically fit entirely on the browser window vertically. I want it to shrink the elements so that it all fits in the browser without a vertical scroll bar. The reason for this is simple, it will be a landing page that is mobile app inspired, press the button and it will take you to where you need to go. However, users will have different screen sizes/resolutions, so the page must be fluid.

I have managed to get the page to shrink according to the width of the browser, as demonstrated here ([jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Marty_j1/Lykr2/1/)).

```
 container {
    padding: 1% 1%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;/* a max-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too wide on a large monitor. This keeps line length more readable. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    /*min-width: 780px;/* a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too narrow. This keeps line length more readable in the side columns. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */
}
```

As you can see, all elements shrink dynamically based on the width of the browser. However, when viewed on a 1024x768 screen, the bottom row of "buttons" is half cut off by the browser and the user has to scroll to see the rest.

I have tried a few solutions on this site but cannot seem to get it to work. Can anybody here help me to get it to adjust dynamically to the browser's width AND height?

To better illustrate what I would like, this is the effect I would like to see [dynamic resizing example](http://eseb.net/potos.php?f=best_of/indianpeaks_2.jpg)

Here is an image that shows exactly what my problem is [Difference in Resolution http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/5840/resolutionissue.jpg](http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/5840/resolutionissue.jpg)

Note that the spacing between the buttons shrinks due to the percentage spacing but the images will shrink to fit if the window is adjusted horizontally only. I need it to squeeze the whole thing into the browser window.

Comment: Not seeing it.  I'm making the window of your demo all kinds of different sizes and nothing is getting cut off.

Comment: Problem with your HTML... you have **two** `<body>` tags and only one `</body>` tag.  The one left _open_ created by you and the one added by [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marty_j1/Lykr2/1/show).  You should not be using a `<body>` tag inside the jsFiddle's HTML pane.  You also don't need the `onload=` event handler in your `body` tag since you could be doing that with jQuery instead.

Comment: height 100% plus padding 1% 1% will result in a height of 102%. try making that height 98%

Comment: https://github.com/tenactive/Easingscroll-horizontal
Here is a cool frame work for horizontal scroll

Comment: @Sparky, it only resizes when you adjust it horizontally.

Comment: Like I said, I tried all kinds of sizes and nothing was being cut off at any time.

Comment: @Sparky, my apologies. I should have clarified that I am actually using Dreamweaver to put this together. I just put what I was working on into jsFiddle to demonstrate what I have so far.

Comment: @Sparky, so for you its resizing when you adjust the window size vertically? No scroll bars at all?

Comment: When did I say that?? "re-sizing" simply means _to a different size_. And I saw no scrollbars in your jsFiddle demo.

Comment: This is what I see when I resize horizontally and what I see when it is resized vertically [link](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/2497/jsfiddlescreenshot.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your container and child elements (where required) fill the screen vertically you need to ensure that you are also applying a 100% height value to the overall parents of these elements. In your case I would apply the following rule to your css:

```
html,body
{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

This would then cause your container to adapt to 100% of height of the browser window (as container is the child of your overall body which is a child of the html tag). However, as you have applied padding you will still see the vertical scroll bar. You therefore need to ensure that you reduce the height % of your container element in relation to the padding / margins that you apply. In your case as Kai Qing suggests above you should change your container height to 98%.